# arm-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file

Tags: executable

I am trying to build a ROM from AOSP 5.1.1 specifically (Nexus 7 - grouper). However, a while ago I got stuck at this part while building the kernel.

The following command works fine: `make tegra3_android_defconfig`
The problem starts when I write: `make -j4`

It crashes and says:

```
Fahads-MBP:tegra Fahad$ make -j4
/volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: /volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
      CHK     include/linux/version.h
      CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
      UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
      HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
      Generating include/generated/mach-types.h
      CC      kernel/bounds.s
    /bin/sh: /volumes/untitled/tegra/../WORKING_DIRECTORY/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin/arm-eabi-gcc: cannot execute binary file
    make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 126
    make: *** [prepare0] Error 2

    #### make failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

I ran the command

```
chmod 777 arm-eabi-gcc
```

and

```
chmod +x arm-eabi-gcc
```

but still no use. It gives the same cannot execute the binary file error. Any suggestions?

Comment: could you paste the output of running the command file on that file?

Comment: there is no specific output when i run that command

Fahads-MBP:bin Fahad$ chmod +x arm-eabi-gcc

Fahads-MBP:bin Fahad$

Comment: I was not clear. Please run $file arm-eabi-gcc

Comment: arm-eabi-gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped

Answer (score 1):

“Cannot execute binary file” isn't about permissions, so `chmod` won't help you.

(Oh, and never use `chmod 777`. It's never the solution. If you try to execute something and the error is “permission denied”, then add execute permissions: `chmod a+x`.)

This message means that you have a binary file (not a script) that the kernel doesn't recognize as a valid program format. Given the name of the directory `linux-x86`, this is an x86 executable.

Given the prompt, it appears that you're trying to build the kernel on the ARM tablet itself. You can't run an x86 executable on an ARM processor. You'll need compiler binaries for ARM, which are not present in the Android tree. The simplest solution would be to do the build on a PC. If you really want to do the build on the tablet, get appropriate compiler binaries (for the right libc; there are many different ABIs on ARM platforms and identifying the right one can be a bit difficult).

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html and google for `cross compile android on linux`

Comment: @cas And the only supported host platforms are {Linux,Windows,OSX}-{x86,amd64}. ARM host platforms aren't officially supported, and I don't think it would be easy to set up.

Comment: @Gilles I am building the kernel on Darwin, on a Mac 2015 machine. therefore it seems improbably that running an x86 executable on an ARM processor could be the issue. Any other suggestions or routes that you think I should explore?

Comment: @fahad Ah, ok. Same difference: you're attempting to run a Linux binary on OSX. I don't know why the build scripts are picking that up. Try following the [guide](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) mentioned by cas. You might need to call `make-standalone-toolchain.sh`.